# Is there elastic resistor material?

Tags: resistors, variable

Is there elastic resistor material?

I want to measure the respiratory rate and smoothness of each breath. And it would appear that a brute force solution to this problem could be a belt around the stomach that would stretch with each breath, the change in resistance as stomach expands could signal the rate and smoothness of each breath.

Comment: Search term: "Strain Gauge"

Comment: Have you considered a simple inductance plethysmograph?

Comment: The field of Soft Robotics has a few techniques for flexible sensors: resistive, capacitive, pressure sensor based.. https://softroboticstoolkit.com/sensors

Answer (score 0):

A piezoelectric strip will *generate* a (quite large) voltage as it is flexed. It is also thin and flexible and wouldn't interfere with breathing.